# Splitting Column Lists in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm looking for an good way to solve the following problem. My current fix is not particularly clean, and I'm hoping to learn from your insight.

Suppose I have a Panda DataFrame, whose entries look like this:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],columns=['Color','Texture','IsGlass'])

>>> df['Color']=[np.nan,['Red','Blue'],['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']]
>>> df['Texture']=[['Rough'],np.nan,['Silky', 'Shiny', 'Fuzzy']]
>>> df['IsGlass']=[1,0,1]

>>> df
                            Color                   Texture   IsGlass
    1                         NaN                  ['Rough']        1
    2              ['Red', 'Blue']                       NaN        0 
    3  ['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']  ['Silky','Shiny','Fuzzy']       1
```

So each observation in the index corresponds to something I measured about its color, texture, and whether it's glass or not. What I'd like to do is turn this into a new "indicator" DataFrame, by creating a column for each observed value, and changing the corresponding entry to a one if I observed it, and NaN if I have no information.

```
>>> df
         Red Blue Green Purple Rough Silky Shiny Fuzzy Is Glass               
    1    Nan  Nan  Nan   Nan    1     NaN   Nan   Nan     1        
    2     1    1   Nan   Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan     0 
    3    Nan   1    1     1     Nan    1     1     1      1
```

I have solution that loops over each column, looks at its values, and through a series of Try/Excepts for non-Nan values splits the lists, creates a new column, etc., and concatenates.

This is my first post to StackOverflow - I hope this post conforms to the posting guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: You data format is string or list ?['Blue, Green, Purple'] ? or ['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']

Comment: Thank you. It is ['Blue','Green','Purple']. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Add my solution ~ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacking Hacks!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df = df.stack().unstack(fill_value=[])

def b(c):
    d = mlb.fit_transform(c)
    return pd.DataFrame(d, c.index, mlb.classes_)

pd.concat([b(df[c]) for c in ['Color', 'Texture']], axis=1).join(df.IsGlass)

   Blue  Green  Purple  Red  Fuzzy  Rough  Shiny  Silky IsGlass
1     0      0       0    0      0      1      0      0       1
2     1      0       0    1      0      0      0      0       0
3     1      1       1    0      1      0      1      1       1
```

Comment: We using `MultiLabelBinarizer` is because of speed ?

Comment: @Wen first thing that came to mind and no time to provide options

Comment: Got it :-) LOL!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because I learned the most from it. The other answers are great, and what I asked for, but your answer lets me run it over a list of keys easily.

In the actual problem I'm working on, my columns have entries that are strings when one observation is made and a list of strings when two or more are made. A column may look like ['Red',['Red,'Blue'],'Green']. MLB isn't well suited to deal with it in that instance, but I managed a work around. If you have more insight to share on other preprocessing tools that would handle that, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am just using `pandas`, `get_dummies`

```
l=[pd.get_dummies(df[x].apply(pd.Series).stack(dropna=False)).sum(level=0) for x in ['Color','Texture']]
pd.concat(l,axis=1).assign(IsGlass=df.IsGlass)
Out[662]: 
   Blue  Green  Purple  Red  Fuzzy  Rough  Shiny  Silky  IsGlass
1     0      0       0    0      0      1      0      0        1
2     1      0       0    1      0      0      0      0        0
3     1      1       1    0      1      0      1      1        1
```

Comment: @AdamAzzam Yw~ Good night

Answer (score 1):

For each texture/color in each row, I check if the value is null. If not, we add that value as a column = 1 for that row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3],columns=['Color','Texture','IsGlass'])

df['Color']=[np.nan,['Red','Blue'],['Blue', 'Green', 'Purple']]
df['Texture']=[['Rough'],np.nan,['Silky', 'Shiny', 'Fuzzy']]
df['IsGlass']=[1,0,1]

for row in df.itertuples():

    if not np.all(pd.isnull(row.Color)):
        for val in row.Color:
            df.loc[row.Index,val] = 1     

    if not np.all(pd.isnull(row.Texture)):
        for val in row.Texture:
            df.loc[row.Index,val] = 1
```